# type-checking function signatures with less or more arguments

Tags: flowtype

This is about Flow typechecking pronouncements when a function type is defined and the function expression we're trying to typecheck has: (a) more or (b) fewer arguments than the defined type.

The following typechecks as it should, no questions here.

```
declare type TFunctionNumberToBoolean = (n: number) => boolean;
const f: TFunctionNumberToBoolean = function isEven(n: number) {return n%2==0;}
```

The following case (*case A*) where the normative "number to boolean" function type is changed as follows:

(<del>n:  number</del>) => boolean

… doesn't typecheck:

```
declare type TFunctionNumberToBoolean = () => boolean;

const f: TFunctionNumberToBoolean = function isEven(n: number) {return n%2==0;}
```

The following case (*case B*) where the normative "number to boolean" function type is changed as follows:

(n: number**, foo :number**) => boolean

… typechecks:

```
declare type TFunctionNumberToBoolean = (n: number, foo: number) => boolean;

const f: TFunctionNumberToBoolean = function isEven(n: number) {return n%2==0;}
```

What is the reasoning behind *Case A* (more arguments than the defined function type) not typechecking but *Case B* (less arguments than the defined function type) typechecking ? I naively think that an argument could be made for the opposite behavior to have been more intuitive.

I am using Flow 0.35.

Comment: It may been good to clarify your examples, since I took me a minute to realize you were asking about the zero-args vs two-args case, when passing a function with one arg.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a function that takes two properties of an object and sums them:

```
function sum(obj) {
  return obj.a + obj.b;
}
```

What happens if you pass additional arguments? Nothing bad, it will be ignored.

What happens if you pass no arguments? You'll get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'a' of undefined`.

Passing more arguments is safe, passing less arguments is unsafe.

Comment: Flow complains when you provide a function implementation that uses *more* arguments than the function type.

Comment: Because using this type you will pass _less_ arguments than are actually required for function implementation